# Faset filters / Filters in Search Results Prestashop

Tags: search, prestashop, prestashop-modules

I'm looking for some solution ready to use or some hint on how to achieve it manually to build. I'm trying to build filters in Prestashop 1.7x in search results. The default solution offers only Sorting, which is not perfect for the users.

Maybe someone had a similar case and can help?

The goal I'd like achieve:

[image]

Comment: This question sounds a little bit OT here, anyway for simple filtered search you can rely on the built-in module "ps_facetedsearch", or if you need a result similar to the posted screen check for paid e-commerce search engines like SniperFast.

Comment: @user3256843 Thank you for the reply. Yes, I'm using ps_facetedsearch in catalogs as default, etc. but as I understand there is no easy way to just reuse this module in search results? I had also a similar case with manufacturers.

Comment: No, you can't use native faceted search in search bar, if you cannot code your own you'll need to rely  on paid addons module or external search engine.

Comment: The cost of modifying this module is higher than purchasing a third-party solution. Go for module like "Amazing Filter" or "Advanced Search" :)